# GCM always returning SENDER_INVALID

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

GCM is always returning SENDER_INVALID with following code..

All I could find is project id to be valid, which is valid and i have also tried changing the project but that is not helping.

I also tried going though entire stackoverflow and google groups, also changing google account and tried creating Application with old and as well new Google API console.

```
public class GCM {
    private static final String TAG = "GCM";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    Context mContext=null;
    Activity mActivity=null;
    String SENDER_ID = "44843754432";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid;
    public GCM(Context ctx, Activity act){
        mContext=ctx;
        mActivity=act;
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
    }
    public String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("DealsGeo_GCM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, PROPERTY_REG_ID);
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    public boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, mActivity, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
    public void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG,"Registering "+SENDER_ID);
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    storeRegistrationId(mContext, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Error: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
                return msg;
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("DealsGeo_GCM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(mContext);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a URL like https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect#project:**581054524740**:access in your project google console, so you must put the sender code : 581054524740

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot a digit when copying the Google API project ID.
Your project ID - `44843754432` - has 11 digits, while all the project IDs I've seen had 12 digits.

Comment: Generated new ID with new project, which is 12 Digits.. But still no luck :(